Distance from function to subspace in Hilbert space
Consider the space $H = L^2[0,1]$ and the subspace
$$W = \{f\in H \:|\: \int_{0}^{1/2} f(x)=0\}.$$
Find the distance of the function $x^2$ to the subspace $W$. First off, the distance is well defined because $W$ is a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $L^2[0,1]$
Now, the usual way I would go about these kinds of problems is observing that the condition that the integral be zero implies we know about the orthonormal to the space $W$ and then find an orthonormal basis and proceed. However, that would apply if the integral were from $0$ to $1$ since it would be the inner product of $f$ with $1$, but it is not the case here. How could one obtain orthonormal bases for either $W$ or $W^\perp$ if we do not have such inner product form?

If you want the integral over $[0,1]$ you can multiply by $\chi_{[0,1/2]}(x)$

Follow @SineoftheTime's remark and project $x \mapsto x^2$ onto the half plane $W$. The general formula for any Hilbert space is straightforward to write down and has a nice geometric interpretation. There is no need to get an explicit basis.

There is a general procedure. Let $W=w^\perp$ for a nonzero element $w$ and let $v\notin W.$ Then find the distance from $v$ to $W.$ It suffices to consider the two dimensional space spanned by $w$ and $v.$ Draw a picture. You will notice that the solution has something to do with the Pythagoras theorem.
